# How to hash last insert id and set into request then save into db in laravel.?

Tags: laravel, hash, eloquent

Below my request is perfectly fine. I just wonder is it best way to use save function two time?.its really bothering me I am looking for a best way to hashed last insert id and set into visitor_id to save into db.
Remember before hashing visitor_id i am sending `$request->visitor_id NULL`.

Here is my request:

```
$visit->funnel_id = $request->funnel_id;

$visit->page_id = $request->page_id;
$visit->traffic_source_id = $request->traffic_source_id;
$visit->visitor_id = $request->visitor_id;
$visit->save();

$hashid = new Hashid();
$visit->visitor_id = $hashid->encode($visit->id);
$visit->save();
```

Comment: Is visitor Id - Auto incremented primary key?

Comment: @SurenderSinghRawat  Don't interpreted the visitor_id name as ID of some table. I mean in terms of database its not a foreign key or primary key of some table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add 'nextId' function and include `Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB` facade in your Visitor model.

```
public function nextId(){
   $statement = DB::select("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE '".$this->getTable()."'");
   return $statement[0]->Auto_increment;
}
```

You can implement in your code like this :

```
$visit->funnel_id = $request->funnel_id;

$visit->page_id = $request->page_id;
$visit->traffic_source_id = $request->traffic_source_id;
$hashid = new Hashid();
$visit->visitor_id = $hashid->encode($visit->nextId());
$visit->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $visit->funnel_id = $request->funnel_id;

 $visit->page_id = $request->page_id; 
 $visit->traffic_source_id = $request->traffic_source_id; 
 $visit->visitor_id = $request->visitor_id; 
 $visit->save();

 $hashid = new Hashid(); 
 $hashid->visitor_id = $visit->id;
 $hashid->save();
```

Comment: U r using two time save function. My lines of code is working fine i am just looking for best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$hashid = new Hashid();
$visit->visitor_id = $hashid->\Hash::make($visit->id);
$visit->save();
```

Or

```
$hashid = new Hashid();
$visit->visitor_id = $hashid->$visit->id;
$visit->save();
```

Comment: I think u r not getting my point  i am already doing this. I am looking for best solution means looking for line of code that will not have to use save function multiple time.